# Bootstrap tooltip is not working in ASP.NET form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

In my control I defined text box having a tooltip:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox  name="ReportYear" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtReportYear" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Year" MaxLength="4" ClientIDMode="Static" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Provide a Year"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

In my javascript file I have defined the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('#txtReportYear').tooltip('hide');
});
```

as explained in [Bootstrap Tutorial](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

In my `master` page I declared all the references to `.js` files

```
......
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/a360.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/validations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">    
                <h1>A360 Statement Generator</h1>
                <p>This application is used to generate A360 PDS statements</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">

        </div>      
    </form>
.....
```

However, my tooltip is not black like in tutorial and cannot be placed on top of the text box

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you check the console . are you getting any error in it?

Comment: Yes, I did. No errors

Comment: How is your tool tip you are getting, and for which control you are applying tooltip? i cant see in code

Comment: I'm applying tooltip to a textbox inside a form.

Comment: any sample output how you are getting

Comment: I have a link to a tutorial's page on what I'm expecting from my tooltip. What I'm getting is white tooltip above textbox when I roll mouse over the control

Comment: i think your Bootstrap css is getting over ridded

Comment: What can it be overriden with?

Comment: you need to see using inspect element